# TypeError: 'int' object is not iterable. Python error when using map() inside a function

Tags: python, dictionary, iterable

I'm trying to learn different methods for adding corresponding elements in list. 
Currently stuck here, code works fun when i'm not using a function. 
Assistance?

```
from operator import add
#Setting up the lists
matrix_a = [23,1,4,8]
matrix_b = [3,11,3,2]

def add(in_list1,in_list2):
   final_list = list(map(add, in_list1, in_list2))

   return final_list

matrix_c = add(matrix_a,matrix_b)
print(matrix_c)
```

Answer (score 1):

You have two `add` functions here, one you import from operator and one that you make yourself, change your `def add` to something else such as `def add2` and change the function calls appropriately.

Answer (score 0):

Name your function something other than `add`. You've overwritten the name `add` that you imported from `operator`, so `add` in `list(map(add, in_list1, in_list2))` refers to your own function.

Answer (score 0):

Change function name and list creation:

```
matrix_a = [23,1,4,8]
matrix_b = [3,11,3,2]

def sum(in_list1,in_list2):
    return[*map(lambda x, y: x +y, in_list1, in_list2)]

print(sum(matrix_a,matrix_b))
```

Comment: The OP's problem is name conflicts, and you suggest using a builtin name?